# What do you call the front of a lecture hall?

Tags: word-request

[image]

What do you call the front of a lecture hall? Is there a word for it? Some don't have a platform and there's just this empty area. I don't think it would be called a stage or anything like that, but I can't think of a specific word for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no commonly used word for this.

> The professor is standing at the front of the lecture hall

is how most people would describe your photo.